# BinarySearchTree's insert function in javascript

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

I was building a BinarySearchTree by using javascript

but the insert function in my code deoesn't run what i want

my ideal result is

> {"value":9,"left":{"value":4,"left":{"value":1,"left":null,"right":null},"right":{"value":6,"left":null,"right":null}},"right":{"value":20,"left":{"value":15,"left":null,"right":null},"right":{"value":170,"left":null,"right":null}}}

but my result is

> '{"value":9,"left":null,"right":{"left":null,"right":{"left":null,"right":{"left":null,"right":{"left":null,"right":{"left":null,"right":{"left":null,"right":null}}}}}}}'

I think the problem is in my insert function

Here is my JS:

```js
  
      class Node {
        constructor(value){
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
        this.value = value;
      }
     }

class BinarySearchTree {
  constructor(){
    this.root = null;
  }
  insert(value){
    var root=this.root
    if(!root){
      this.root=new Node(value)
    }else{
      var currentNode=root;
      var newNode=new Node(value)
      while(currentNode){
      if(value<currentNode.value){
        if(!currentNode.left){
          currentNode.left=new Node;
          break;
        }
        else{
          currentNode=currentNode.left;
        }
       }else{
        if(!currentNode.right){
          currentNode.right=new Node;
           break;
        }else{
          currentNode=currentNode.right
        }
      }
    }
  }

  }
  lookup(value){
     var root=this.root
     var searchNode = new Node(value)
     if(!this.root){
        return null;
      }
    if(searchNode===root){
       return root
    }else{
   if(searchNode.value>root){
       return root.right.value
      }else{
        return root.left.value
      }
    }
   }
   }

  const tree = new BinarySearchTree();
  tree.insert(9)
  tree.insert(4)
  tree.insert(6)
  tree.insert(20)
  tree.insert(170)
  tree.insert(15)
  tree.insert(1)
  JSON.stringify(traverse(tree.root))

  //     9
 //  4     20
 //1  6  15  170

  function traverse(node) {
  const tree = { value: node.value };
  tree.left = node.left === null ? null : traverse(node.left);
  tree.right = node.right === null ? null : traverse(node.right);
  return tree;
  }
```

Comment: Just filter out all null items...

Comment: `newNode` not `new Node`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Node class` was instantiated as `newNode` so change all `new Node` into `newNode` ***except for the first instance of `new Node`** of course.

> ```
> var newNode=new Node(value) // Leave this one alone and fix the rest
> var searchNode = new Node(value) // Leave this one alone as well
> ```
>
> ```js
> var insertNode = function(node, newNode) {
>   if (newNode.key < node.key) { 
>     if (node.left === null) { 
>       node.left = newNode; 
>     } else {
>       insertNode(node.left, newNode); 
>     }
>   } else {
>     if (node.right === null) {
>       node.right = newNode; 
>     } else {
>       insertNode(node.right, newNode); 
>     }
>   }
> };
> ```

Comment: No problem, that BST looked familiar and then I remembered it was from an ebook I had read  